# vtiger: Relationship with extra information

Tags: crm, vtiger

I would like to have a one-to-many relationship with extra information attached: Each organisation has a customer-id for a specific vendor (because purchase orders are processed in the name of the organisation).

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If one organization can be related to only one vendor (have uitype 10 field), best way to store vendor specific Id - make additional field for organization. If relation is many-to-many - you have to add special table (like OrgToVendorRel) to store relation data. And all necessary functions to process it.

Oleg
Oleg.a@pinstudio.ru